# MySQL Subquery error: SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'id'

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling to get the following MySQL statement to work.

```
SELECT ItemGroup.users_id,ItemGroup.comments_id,ItemGroup.uploads_id,ItemGroup.posts_id, 
                Comment.id,Comment.uploads_id,
                CommentUpload.id,
                Upload.id,
                Post.id
                FROM items AS ItemGroup
                LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT Comment.id, Comment.uploads_id, CommentUpload.id, CommentUpload.uuid
                    FROM comments As Comment
                    INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT CommentUpload.id, CommentUpload.uuid
                        FROM uploads AS CommentUpload
                        ) CommentUpload ON CommentUpload.id = Comment.uploads_id
                    GROUP BY Comment.uploads_id
                ) Comment ON Comment.id = ItemGroup.comments_id
                LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT Upload.id
                    FROM uploads AS Upload
                    ) Upload ON Upload.id = ItemGroup.uploads_id
                LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT Post.id
                    FROM posts AS Post
                    ) Post ON Post.id = ItemGroup.posts_id
                WHERE ItemGroup.users_id = {$__cakeID__$}
                AND (
                Comment.id IS NOT NULL 
                OR Upload.id IS NOT NULL 
                OR Post.id IS NOT NULL
                )
                LIMIT 0 , 300
```

I'm trying to find the uploads related to comments but it is throwing SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'id'.

I'm sure it's something small but I just can't find what i'm doing wrong and I'd really appreciate some help.

Thank you for your time!

Alex

Comment: The statement is not complete currently. It doesn't begin with `SELECT`, `CREATE`, ... So it's difficult to answer the question.

Comment: Hi Romain,

Sorry about that, missed out the SELECT during the copy and paste. Not very helpful, I know.

Thank you.

Alex

Comment: What value does `{$__cakeID__$}` get to have? Are you using this statement as part of a `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: I've managed to fix this thank you.

It was the calling of different .ids I had to create aliases for the fields as well as the tables...

{$__cakeID__$} was simply an input variable and it was select statement to retrieve data.

Thank you for the time you took to help me!

/A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant name two tables with same alias `FROM comments As Comment` and `GROUP BY Comment.uploads_id) Comment`, use `Comment_A` and `Comment_B` for example.

Comment: Hi Tomas

Thanks for the advice. I've renamed all the comments to different things as you have suggested but I'm still getting the duplicate column name. 

If I remove the Inner join it all works but I can't narrow it down any further.

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: In INNER JOIN you also have duplicated alias `INNER JOIN (SELECT CommentUpload.id, CommentUpload.uuid FROM uploads AS CommentUpload) CommentUpload`, did you update this one also?

Comment: Yes, I think so. This is the current code:

`LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT Comment_B.id, Comment_B.uploads_id, CommentUpload_A.id
      FROM comments As Comment_B
      INNER JOIN (
       SELECT CommentUpload_B.id, CommentUpload_B.uuid
       FROM uploads AS CommentUpload_B
       ) CommentUpload_A ON CommentUpload_A.id = Comment_B.uploads_id
      GROUP BY Comment_B.uploads_id
     ) Comment_A ON Comment_A.id = ItemGroup.comments_id`

Comment: I've managed to fix this thank you. It was the calling of different .ids I had to create aliases for the fields as well as the tables...  Thank you for the time you took to help me! /A